# Like a specific post of the timeline of a Facebook page from an external website

Tags: facebook, post, button, web, external

I've some trouble with the Like Button. I would like to like a specific post like this one from a external website but it doesn't work:
https://www.facebook.com/236086869778323/posts/597301643656842
For this button I used the following code, which is given by Facebook Developers

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/236086869778323/posts/597302473656759" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read the documentation about the Like Button it states

> A single click on the Like button will 'like' **pieces of content on the web** and share them on Facebook. You can also display a Share button next to the Like button to let people add a personal message and customize who they share with.

These pieces of content are external. That is the Like Button is intended to be used for webpages *outside* of Facebook to share in Facebook.

You will need to use Embedded Posts instead https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/